# Is it possible to submit ipa to app store?

Tags: app-store, ipa

I know that how can create the ipa file. I am using ad-hoc provision profile and demonstrate to client. Now I change the ad-hoc provision profile to app store distribution provision profile and after that create the ipa file

Generally I compress the app and submit zip file to app loader .so I want to ask that can i submit the ipa to to app loader for approval the application on app store.

Answer (score 1):

This might help http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16504

I have just uploaded an ipa file to app store with application loader. It is successfully uploaded.

Comment: It is better to post the actual answer not just a link to the answer.